# Ionic 3 otp autoverfication

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Hi I am working on a project that needs auto otp verification,Once the user enters phone no.I have checked on the internet,examples are there for ionic 1 angular 1.I need examples for ionic 3 with typescript.Please help me with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you and idea which hows auto otp verifications. Sometimes it will use for forgot password

```
Pre requisites:

 1. Backend Server
 2. SMS Server
 3. Ionic app
 4. Idea on REST API
```

You can setup two restapi url which triggered the backend to send the SMS OTP heres my example

```
 1. /sendOtp - backend api which ionic call to send the OTP

  ionic app -> sendOTP api -> SMS server -> ionic app.

  a. ionic app : send info like phone number, type ex. reset-password and generated reference code
  b. sendOTP api :  it will generate a 6 digit otp and save in the database and send to SMS server
  c. SMS server : it will send to phone number
  d. ionic app : it will open otp page while waiting the OTP


 2. /verifyOtp - backend api which verify the otp generated from backend and match to the database.

  ionic app -> verifyOtp api -> SMS server -> ionic app

  a. ionic app : after receiving the otp digit i will send the otp with reference code to verifyOtp api
  b. verifyOtp api : i will accept and check if will match in the database and generate temporary password
  c. SMS Server : i will send the temporary password to the ionic app.
  d. ionic app : you can prompt thank you page or redirect to change password
```

You can designed the api defends on what you need.